# Generate 8 digit varchar with 4 alpha and 4 numeric in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to generate a unique varchar ID, that should contain 4 digits of Alphabets and 4 digits of Numbers. They can be random, but the ID should start with alphabets and then numbers should follow. This is in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Eg:

ABCD1234
rtfd8798
tyry8745

Could anyone help?

Comment: Why you are not using newid()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to produce exactly 4 random alphabetical characters followed by four random numbers, the following will accomplish it.

It's not pretty or flexible, but should be enough to lead you in the right direction.

```
DECLARE @Data   VARCHAR(8)
SET @Data = ''

-- Build first four characters
WHILE (LEN(@Data) < 4)
BEGIN
    SET @Data = @Data + SUBSTRING('abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ', CAST(RAND() * 52 AS INT), 1)
END
-- Build next for numbers
WHILE (LEN(@Data) < 8)
BEGIN
    SET @Data = @Data + SUBSTRING('0123456789', CAST(RAND() * 10 AS INT), 1)
END

PRINT @Data
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution in my opinion is to use `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblProducts
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   ProductID AS 'PUID' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Then when you insert new data into table values like `PUID0001`, `PUID0002`